# which of the following statement is TRue ?.....

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

let $f : R \rightarrow R$ be a continious and nonnegative function.

which of the following statement  is TRue ?

a) if there exist  $ c \in (0,1)$ such that  $f(c) = 100$ then $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx \ge  \frac {1}{2}.$

b)$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx > \frac {1}{2}$.then $f(c) > \frac{1}{2}$ for  some  $c \in (0,1).$

c)$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \frac {1}{2}$ then there exist  $c\in (0,1)$ such that $f(c) = \frac {1}{2}$

d) None of these

My answer  : option b) and C)   is true.. by intermediate theorem

For option a)  if  i take $f(x) = 200x$ now  put $x = \frac{1}{2}$..then  $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \frac {200 x^2}{2} |_0^1$...we will not get $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx =  \frac {1}{2}.$..so option a) is false

Is its right or  wrong ??  Pliz tell me

Any hints/ solution

Comment: How does your example prove that _a)_ is false?

Comment: if  i take $f(x) = 200x$ now  put $x = \frac{1}{2}$..then  $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \frac {200 x^2}{2} |_0^1$...we will not get $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx =  \frac {1}{2}.$..so option a) is false

Comment: How does this show that _a)_ is false? Did you state it incorrectly? You wrote $...\geq \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: yes  i mean its satisfied $>$   but  not  $=  $  so  its is false

Comment: $a\geq b$ is true if either $a>b$ or $a=b$

Comment: I would agree that a) is false but your example does not show that.  You need to find a function $f$ and a value of $c$ for which $f(c) = 100$ but the value of the integral is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.  

For b) and c) I think that you need to say much more.

Comment: Equivalently, $a\geq b$ is true if and only if $a < b$ is false.

Comment: thanks@badjohn,,,

Comment: @JoBe..thanks  i got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same vein as GNU Supporter's answer, but not as elementary (and neat :D)

---

Consider another "peak function", namely 
$$f(x) = 100\ e^{-a(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}\ .$$
Clearly $f(\frac{1}{2}) = 100.$ We can compute

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 100\ e^{-a(x-1/2)^2} \ dx 
&= 100 \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}} e^{-a x^2} \ dx \\
&= \frac{100}{\sqrt{a}} \int_{-\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}}^{\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}} e^{-x^2} \ dx \\
&= \frac{100 }{\sqrt{a}} \sqrt{\pi}\ \mathsf{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
where $\mathsf{erf}$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). Now, all we have to do is find for what values of $a$

\begin{align*}
\frac{100 }{\sqrt{a}} \sqrt{\pi}\ \mathsf{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{2}\right) < \frac{1}{2}\ .
\end{align*}
This can be solved with WolframAlpha, and the answer is roughly $a\geq 125\ 664$.

So an example would be with $a = 100^3$, and we get
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 100\ e^{-100^3 (x-1/2)^2} \ dx \approx 0.177 < \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

You're in the right direction by invoking the MVT to prove (b) and (c).

It remains to show that (a) is false by providing a counterexample: consider a "peak" function which is piecewise linear by joining the points $(0,0)$, $(c-\delta,0),(c,100),(c+\delta,0)$ and $(1,0)$.  This traces a triangle with height and base width $100$ and $2\delta$ respectively.  The area under the graph is $100\delta$.  To make it smaller than $0.5$, set $\delta < 0.05$.